How Do You Make Eclipse Show All Elements in Outline View as Collapsed by Default?
When I use Eclipse now (2024-06), if I open a class into the Editor, the Outline View shows all the subclasses fully expanded and all methods fully expanded to show any anonymous classes. However, I don't want all my subclasses and methods to be fully expanded. I can get what I want if I click on "Collapse All" and then expand the top-level type, but this means I have to do that every time I switch to a new class. However, I would like the Outline View to do this by default, and I could swear this is what the default behavior used to be when I have used Eclipse in the past, but now it doesn't seem to work that way.
I have tried to find anything about this online but have come up short. This Eclipse Formus post from 2008 seems to think it is not possible to do, but I thought at one time I had things configured to work this way, but now I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to just display one level of items in the Outline View by default.
Did Eclipse change this recently? Is there a way to configure it to work like I think it used to?
UPDATE: Eclipse did used to work the way I remember (quite recently, in fact). So, is there a setting somewhere in the preferences that now controls this, so that I can set it back to the way it used to be?

The forum post dates back to 2009 and the project manager at the time, Dani Megert, who passed away in 2020, said "There's no such option". I'm also not aware of such an option. So if you think such an option is a good idea, you might consider to contribute it by doing a pull request in the JDK UI project here.

So, in order to verify that I am not crazy, I downloaded a slightly older version of Eclipse (2023-12) and found that it does exactly what I desire (and what I remember) when I click on a class and look at the Outline View. (In other words, the subclasses aren't expanded by default.) So, it looks like Eclipse changed how this works in recent versions. In light of this, I guess my question is whether there is some configuration/setting where I can change it back to how it definitely used to work.

Then it might be a regression, causing maybe this part of code not being executed or applied anymore. Please report it or better, provide a pull request.

Thanks for the suggestion @howlger. I have submitted a bug report as I couldn't find it already reported.

Thanks, but that's the wrong bug tracker (of the E4 project that has been archived). Please make sure it has been reported here: https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues

Okay, now I've submitted the issue on the GitHub page. Thanks for the help, @howlger. As you can tell, I've never done that before. I'm surprised an archived project let me submit a bug still.
